# I need a website to show alert if button was pressed in 30 seconds after page has loaded, but not if 31 seconds or more. Can someone help me?

Tags: html, css, timer, countdown

I need a pop up saying were sorry if button was pressed in 30 seconds after loading the page

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" 
id="popupBoxAccept">Submit
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>

<script>
var tim = setTimeout(function(){
$('#popupBoxAccept').click();
},1000);
$('#popupBoxAccept').click(function(){
clearTimeout(tim);
alert('We are sorry')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable to hold whether it's before the cut-off time or not.

Also it's recommended to add your code to one of jQuery's ready/load events... https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

NB: I set the timer for 10 seconds here.

```js
var tooearly = true;

var tim = setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('Time complete.');
   tooearly = false;
}, 10000);


$('#popupBoxAccept').click(function(){
  //clearTimeout(tim);
  console.log('button clicked... tooearly=='+tooearly);
  if(tooearly){
    alert('We are sorry')
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" 
id="popupBoxAccept">Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
```

** I commented out the `clearTimeout(tim);` But if you want that when the user clicks the button before the time is completed, to still show the alert even if they click it again after the time span, then un-comment the `clearTimeout(tim);`